# Eclipse & JSP: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAttributeInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/String;ZZ)V

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-3.4

I'm using Eclipse 3.4 with WTP 3.0.2 and running a fairly large Dynamic Web Project. I've set up the project so that I can access it at http://127.0.0.1:8080/share/ but whenever I do, I get the following error:

```
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAttributeInfo.(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/String;ZZ)V
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.createAttribute(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:572)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.createTagInfo(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:401)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.parseTLD(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:248)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:162)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:423)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:492)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1552)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:126)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:211)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:155)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:276)
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:264)
  at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:563)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:303)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

As none of the above files is my own, pointing out the cause of the problem is quite hard. Any ideas where to start looking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up answering my own question: the problem was that among the necessary JARs that I had added to Tomcat was a conflicting servlet.jar. When I removed this, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a Tomcat path in "Preferences->Tomcat->Advanced->Tomcat base" ?

Try to clean that path (getting back to default configuration), and check if that does solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

most probably the tomcat plugin in the eclipse cause the conflict problem, i manage to solve the problem by getting the same version jar file and override it in the tomcat plugin in the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I had fixed this problem by Ensuring that i have correct version of **servlet.jar** in the classpath that is being taken by my application and also i had kept old **J2EE.jar** file in the classpath and that was causing the main problem. Hence I removed it from the classpath to ensure that it uses by default files.

Comment: This will only cause future trouble. You should NEVER include server-specific libraries in webapp-specific library like `/WEB-INF/lib`. You should NEVER copy/duplicate loose server-specific JAR files around. `servlet.jar` is Tomcat specific. `j2ee.jar` is Glassfish specific. Don't mix them. Keep them there where they belongs, in the server's library. All you basically need to do is to add its file system path to the classpath (build path). In Eclipse, all you need to do is to integrate the server in *Servers* view and associate it with project by *Targeted Runtime* in project properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running Eclipse Helios, with Maven handling dependencies and using Jetty as webserver. After updating to Spring 3.1 I suddenly got this problem, but only on my local development machine.

I first deleted the spring and jetty folders in my local maven repository and updated the dependencies, but that didn't improve the situation.

Then I just deleted the servlet-api and servlet-api-2.5 folders that comes with jetty (but leaving everything else), I got it to work.

All hail the magic of the classpath.